# android - Firebase phone authentication recaptch

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication, firebase-authentication, sha256

I'm working on an android app which require Firebase phone authentication, When I released my app, a recapture still required as in debug mode, I enabled  `Android Device Verification` in google cloud console, also I added google play console `SHA-256`, `SHA-1` to Firebase project setting.
Bellow my Kotlin code of Firebase authentication:

```
fun initFirebase() {
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
}

fun sendOtp(mobile: String, resend: Boolean) {
    if (resend) resend(mobile)
    else send(mobile)
}

private fun send(mobile: String) {
    val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
        .setPhoneNumber(mobile)
        .setTimeout(5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .setActivity(requireActivity())
        .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)
        .build()
    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
}
```

Also at many time I get `VerificationFailed` without getting reason of this failure

---

```
private val mCallbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    override fun onVerificationCompleted(authCredential: PhoneAuthCredential) {}

    override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
        events.value = Constant.EVENT_SEND_FAILED
         Log.v("TAG","VerificationFailed")
    }

    override fun onCodeSent(
        verificationId: String,
        forceResendingToken: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
    ) {
        Log.v("TAG","Success")
}
```

and in verification fragment:

```
private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
var mVerificationId: String = ""
fun verifyOtp(otp: String) {
    val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        mVerificationId,
        otp
    )

    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(requireActivity()) {

        if (it.isSuccessful) {
            mAuth.currentUser?.getIdToken(true)?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful && task.result != null) {
                    val phoneVerificationToken = task.result.token
                    if (phoneVerificationToken != null) {
                        Log.v("TAG","Success")
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.v("TAG","Error")
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.v("TAG","Invalid code")
        }
    }
}
```